# How can i show one loading state for multiple BLoC's?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm developing e commerce app using Bloc pattern. On my homepage, i have multiple widgets with their own bloc structures inside.What i want to do is instead of showing each bloc's own state loading screen, I want to show a single loading screen until all of them are loaded on homepage.

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final SliderBloc sliderBloc = SliderBloc();
  final PopularMarketsBloc popularMarketsBloc = PopularMarketsBloc();
  final PopularBrandsBloc popularBrandsBloc = PopularBrandsBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(context),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: defaultPadding,
            child: MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => sliderBloc,
                ),
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => popularMarketsBloc,
                ),
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => popularBrandsBloc,
                ),
              ],
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  HomepageSlider(),
                  HomepagePopularMarkets(),
                  HomepagePopularBrands(),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and here is one of my widgets(they have same bloc structure inside):

```
class HomepageSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomepageSlider({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomepageSlider> createState() => _HomepageSliderState();
}

class _HomepageSliderState extends State<HomepageSlider> {
  SliderBloc get sliderBloc => BlocProvider.of<SliderBloc>(context);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sliderBloc.add(GetSlidersEvent());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    context.read<SliderBloc>().close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    sliderBloc.add(GetSlidersEvent());
    return BlocBuilder<SliderBloc, SliderState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is SlidersLoadedState) {
          final sliderLoadedState = state;
          return CarouselSlider.builder(
            itemCount: sliderLoadedState.sliderList.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
              final urlImage =
                  sliderLoadedState.sliderList.data![index].imageUrl;
              return buildImage(urlImage);
            },
            options: CarouselOptions(
              autoPlay: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              aspectRatio: 2 / 1,
              viewportFraction: 1,
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is SlidersErrorState) {
          return Text(state.errorMessage);
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to do it with blocbuilder but got that error: Another exception was thrown: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final SliderBloc sliderBloc = SliderBloc();
  final PopularMarketsBloc popularMarketsBloc = PopularMarketsBloc();
  final PopularBrandsBloc popularBrandsBloc = PopularBrandsBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar(context),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: defaultPadding,
            child: MultiBlocProvider(
              providers: [
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => sliderBloc,
                ),
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => popularMarketsBloc,
                ),
                BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => popularBrandsBloc,
                ),
              ],
              child: BlocBuilder<SliderBloc, SliderState>(
                builder: (context, sliderState) {
                  if (sliderState is SlidersLoadingState) {
                    return loading(context);
                  } else {
                    return BlocBuilder<PopularMarketsBloc, PopularMarketsState>(
                      builder: (context, marketsState) {
                        if (marketsState is PopularMarketsLoading) {
                          return loading(context);
                        } else {
                          return BlocBuilder<PopularBrandsBloc,
                              PopularBrandsState>(
                            builder: (context, brandsState) {
                              if (brandsState is PopularBrandsLoadingState) {
                                return loading(context);
                              } else {
                                return Column(
                                  children: [
                                    HomepageSlider(),
                                    HomepagePopularMarkets(),
                                    HomepagePopularBrands(),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

    Widget loading(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: LoadingAnimationWidget.twistingDots(
        leftDotColor: secondaryColor,
        rightDotColor: thirdColor,
        size: 75,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Combined bloc and listen to the state changes as follows.

```
// Define your combined BLoC, events, and states
abstract class CombinedEvent {}

class LoadDataEvent extends CombinedEvent {}

abstract class CombinedState {}

class AllLoadedState extends CombinedState {}

class CombinedBloc extends Bloc<CombinedEvent, CombinedState> {
  CombinedBloc() : super(AllLoadedState());

  @override
  Stream<CombinedState> mapEventToState(CombinedEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoadDataEvent) {
      // Dispatch events to individual BLoCs to start loading
      // You may need to adjust this based on how your BLoCs handle loading
      // For illustration purposes, let's assume you have two BLoCs, BlocA and BlocB
      // Replace BlocAEvent and BlocBEvent with your actual events
      context.read<BlocA>().add(BlocAEvent());
      context.read<BlocB>().add(BlocBEvent());

      // You might have more BLoCs to dispatch events to
      // Add more dispatch calls for each BLoC

      // Wait for all BLoCs to complete loading
      await Future.wait([
        context.read<BlocA>().firstWhere((state) => state is LoadedState),
        context.read<BlocB>().firstWhere((state) => state is LoadedState),
        // Add more BLoCs here
      ]);

      // Once all BLoCs have completed loading, emit the AllLoadedState
      yield AllLoadedState();
    }
  }
}
```

the view class should be like

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('E-commerce App'),
      ),
      body: BlocListener<CombinedBloc, CombinedState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AllLoadedState) {
            // All BLoCs have completed loading, navigate to the actual content
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ActualContentPage(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        child: LoadingScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your Bloc code is outdated. You should migrate to the new Bloc on<Event> syntax. Also in a Bloc, we don't have access to the BuildContext.